# How to show success toast message

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am implementing in-app purchase in my project. Purchase is working fine but i want to print toast message when purchase is completely done.

Now it displaying the message even if purchase is not done or having error. I tried many ways but no success. 
here is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String> ();
        skuList.add(ITEM_SKU);
        Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
        querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);

        try {
            Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);

            int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
            if (response == BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
                ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                    String sku = object.getString("productId");
                    String price = object.getString("price");
                    if (sku.equals(ITEM_SKU)) mPremiumUpgradePrice = price;

                    Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku, "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");

                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                    int endingResponse = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                    //restorePurchasedItems();

                    SharedPrefHelper.getInstance(getApplication()).savePurchaseStatus(true);
                    if(pendingIntent != null) {
                        startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), PURCHASE_REQUEST_CODE, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                        restorePurchasedItems();

                    }//if(response == 0)
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item is already owned...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }//for(String thisResponse : responseList)
            }//if
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: share your code...

Comment: Edited my question, please have a look.

Comment: where are you printing success message?

Comment: I have restorePurchasedItems() method, in that i have success message and some extra code.

Comment: Hey, any one got solution.

Answer (score 1):

check this link 
     https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html

And put your toast in this if condition.

```
 int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
 if (response == BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. I have tried the above solution but it still printing the message before purchase as soon as the purchase dialog opens.

Comment: Please help me sir, i want to print message after continue button of the purchase dialog pressed. Please help me out.

Comment: please share your code where you write your toast message

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by calling onActivityResult() callback method.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "CORRECT!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            View toastView = toast.getView();
            TextView viewText = (TextView) toastView.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            viewText.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorSuccessToast));
            toast.show();
```